# MS SQL 2000 and SSL Certificate

Tags: sql-server, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to set up a MS SQL 2000 server to use an already existing SSL certificate installed on the server.

I verified that the certificate shows up in the Personal/Certificate folder of the account that is running the MSSQLSERVER service using the Certificate MMC snap-in.

I also verified that the certificate for the CA is installed under the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities.

Additionally, to make sure that it is using this specific certificate I created a Certificate registry value of type REG_BINARY in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib
```

and I set it to the certificates thumbprint like it mentions in: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276553

Finally, I opened up the Server Network Utility, checked Force protocol encryption, clicked OK, and restarted the MSSQLSERVER service.

Unfortunately, it fails to start and looking at the event log it's failing with:

```
19015: 
Encryption requested but no valid certificate was found. SQL Server terminating.
```

I'm at a loss. Any ideas? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your "issue to" for the certificate matches exactly as the FQDN of the server you're installing and running SQL Server on.   Once it's in the personal store, SQL should start.   I had the same issue.